# How To Get Website Source As Raw Text Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I've been searching everywhere but cant seem to find an answer, i would like to retrieve the source code of a website in raw text, ive tried a few things like

```
    $("#divname").html('<object data="http://example.com/">');
```

But all u get is a div with the website loaded in it and if i change it to .text or .val it wont work :/

Any Help wouls be GREATLY appreciated

Comment: You want the source of YOUR website (same domain where JS code is) or you want the source of some other website?

Answer (score 1):

By using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or [Curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php).

```
<?php
    echo '<div id="divname">' . htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('http://example.com')) . '</div>';
```

Comment: He specifically mentions jquery, why are you even using PHP!?

Answer (score 1):

You can use curl in php (write simple proxy) and call ajax to fetch the page from url

`file.php`:

```
if (isset($_POST['url'])) {
    $ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_POST['url']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
    echo curl_exec($ch);
}
```

and in javascript use ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'file.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {url: 'http://example.com/'},
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(html) {
       // process html
    }
});
```

I use `$.ajax` function because `$.post` will parse the content as html not as text.